# Selecting dropdown option from website using Python script for automation

Tags: python, html

On the website I have to select a specific time duration from the drop down menu as shown in the attached picture. I need to automate it using a Python script. I am having a script in which I need to add this one thing to make the script perfectly customize. Below is some info from the website highlighting the options.

```html
<button id="duration" type="button" class="Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 Buttonreact__StyledButton-sc-glfma3-0 OKxo hJoTEY" aria-expanded="false" style="font-weight: 500; width: 100%;">
    <div aria-hidden="true" class="Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 Flexreact__Flex-sc-1twd32i-0 cwzTQS jYqxGr">
        <i value="calendar_today" size="24" class="Iconreact__Icon-sc-1gugx8q-0 irnoQt material-icons">calendar_today</i>
    </div>
    <div class="Overflowreact__OverflowContainer-sc-7qr9y8-0 jPSCbX" tabindex="-1">7 days</div>
</button>
```

The purpose over here is to change 7 days to 1 month using a Python script.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to do this with [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html).

Comment: Bro I am not programmer, but trying my hands on this for the first time, if you can be very specific please that would be great. I know it can be done with Selenium but the question is how that is why I posted. kindly if you can help.

Comment: If anyone can please provide suggestion how I can just automate this one single thing will be greatful.

Comment: I tried using the below but did not work, dont know which handle to use to fix it
 mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("Duration"))
 mySelect.select_by_visible_text("7 days")
 mySelect.select_by_value("1 month")

Comment: E.g. for clicking the first button something like `driver.find_element_by_id("duration").click()` should work. Then do it similarly for the next buttons.